# Retroactively view Google Analytics data by application version using a segment

Tags: google-analytics

I understand that filters don't retroactively apply to previous data.  I have been learning segments, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly filter my data by the application version.

I have tried adding an `Advanced -> Condition` with `App Version` `contains` `regex for version`, but this doesn't seem to do anything.  I have noticed that the `Preview` and `Test` buttons are disabled.  Am I missing something here?  I am pretty sure that the regex is correct (`1\.1\.0-rc2` to match `1.1.0-rc2`).

Comment: What app are you talking about?  Where does Google Analytics get access to the version number?